# Backbone. how to route to html file

Tags: backbone.js

I have been working with backbone now for a while burt i have not found a way to route to a .html file. is that possible? i want to do that instead av defining all these templates for each route. something like this?

```
routes: {
  "help":         "pages/help/index.html"
}
```

Comment: no, you can't. But u can use action whitch will reload page with url u need. But this is absolutlly wrong usage of router

Comment: Ok, as i suspected. Thanks.